# python import error in Microsoft fabric notebook

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-synapse, microsoft-fabric

I was trying to import some `langchain` modules in a notebook in Microsoft Fabric like below.

The notebook is using Python 3.10

Step 1: `pip install langchain openai` --> successful

Step 2:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
```

getting the below error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/trident_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)

I tried updating the `typing_extensions` module in Python but nothing seems to work.

Can some please help.

Comment: what is the version of `typing_extensions`? Here is a [similar issue](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/6621) related to the versioning

Comment: More info: if your `typing_extensions` version is <= 4.6.0, you cannot import `TypeAliasType`. Works fine for version 4.7.1. [Related issue](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions/issues/159#issuecomment-1631451146)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same scenario in my environment, and I got same error while importing.

[image]

I followed the suggestion by @[anovoselov](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/u/anovoselov) from this [ask](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pip-not-able-to-download-the-azureopenai-for-langchain-llms/259259/7) and now it is working fine for me.

Try to re-import the `typing_extensions` from the `sys.path` before importing the `langchain`.

```
import sys
del sys.modules["typing_extensions"]
```

[image]